# Passing 'current' row to a function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm not quite sure how to ask this, but let me ask by example:

I have a table beyond that I cannot change structure on.  It records cash deposits at ATM-like terminals, and has one column for each denomination of monetary note.  Right now when I need the total value of a deposit I need code like this:

```
(rd.Count_R10 * 10) + (rd.Count_R20 * 20) + (rd.Count_R50 * 50) + (rd.Count_R100 * 100) + (rd.Count_R200 * 200)
```

I would like to write a T-SQL function that gives me that total value, but for any row, not for an entire query, so my function would be something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION DepositTotal
(
    @row ????
)
RETURNS money
AS
BEGIN   
    RETURN (row.Count_R10 * 10) + (row.Count_R20 * 20) + (row.Count_R50 * 50) + (row.Count_R100 * 100) + (row.Count_R200 * 200)
END
```

Then I would call it something like:

```
select
      DepositDate
    , DepositTotal(thisRow)
    , BatchId
from Deposits
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does the solution have to be a Function?  Or is the limiting factor that you can't alter the structure of the table?  You could write a view over the table that adds a column with your total value..

```
CREATE VIEW DepositsWithTotal

select
  Deposits.* -- Expand this - I just don't know your schema
, DepositTotal = (Count_R10 * 10) + (Count_R20 * 20) + (Count_R50 * 50) + (Count_R100 * 100) + (Count_R200 * 200)

from Deposits
```

Then just select from `DepositsWithTotal` instead of `Deposits`

Comment: Or implement the same as a computed column. View is less invasive though as you don't change the underlying table's schema.

Answer (score 2):

This would be useful for modularising code but definitely isn't possible with TSQL functions.

The only way of doing it using a UDF would be to pass in the PK of the row and get the function to look it up (inefficient) or pass in all values individually (cumbersome).

Perhaps worth a suggestion for the Microsoft Connect Site though I've just seen [Brett's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647042/passing-current-row-to-a-function-in-sql-server/4647216#4647216) and indeed Views or Computed Columns do seem to give this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a table-valued function to pass a row to a function (SQL Server 2008 and later). I think a regular scalar function would be a better alternative in your case though.

Comment: Table Valued Parameter I think you mean? I forgot about those.

Comment: @Martin : Yes, I meant a TV parameter : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx